# autorotate uiview

Tags: uiview, autorotate

I have a UITabController app which is definitely autorotating .. but it is rotating off center.

In my -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:, I return YES for both Landscape orientations and for Portrait (not PortraitUpsideDown).  But, again, it is rotating off-center, that is, when it rotates right to LandscapeRight and left to LandscapeLeft, the contents of the UIView appear against the left boundary/margin.

The entire contents of the UIView are embedded in a UIScrollView in order to keep the geometrical arrangement of each content object together, but the appearance against the left margin occurs with or without this enclosure in a UIScrollView.  I have tried to overcome this within my overridden -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and alternately in a -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method, but no luck at all.

FYI, the contents below the top UIView are a ScrollView, a UIImage, a UILabel, a UITextView and a UIButton (from top to bottom).  The reason I started out with a ScrollView is that I was hoping I could place the bottom UIButton to be way below the UITextView ... but this is a challenge for later after I solve the rotation center problem.

Okay, I've figured out what is wrong, but I don't have a clue how to fix it.  When I click on the top-most UIView within IB, I see orientation = Portrait.  When I change that to Landscape, the whole view shifts left just like what happens when the iOS Simulator runs.

For this top-most view, I select Mode = center and nothing changes.

I really need some big-time help here, so thanks in advance

John Love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as autorotation is concerned, I have solved it:

See this [follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931030/ive-asked-this-question-about-uiscrollview-before-and-the-results-make-little-sense-to-me) as to how.

Thanks bunches

**[SOLVED]**